# Keyboard isn't pushing content in webview

Tags: android, webview, keyboard

I have an html/javascript/css/jquery page running in a webview of an Android app.

When the user taps on the login text box the keyboard shows up fine. The problem is that the keyboard actually shows up high enough to completely cover the text box. The webview content isn't pushing up and it isn't scrollable any more than it would if the keyboard wasn't showing.